# Why ClamAV can't scan some files?

Tags: clamav

Whenever I try to execute a ClamAV scan on a file in many of my `bin` directories, it fails with a

> Can't open file or directory ERROR

message. I know it's possible to get ClamdScan to scan the `bin` directory but I can't figure out how. Any suggestions?

```
$ clamdscan /bin/true
/bin/true: Can't open file or directory ERROR

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

I can't find any differences between the `AppArmor` configuration files on the machine where it works and on the machine where it doesn't.  I did get it to scan with a workaround by adding:

```
/bin/** r,
```

to:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.clamd
```

But this line isn't present on the other machine's local `clamd` `AppArmor` permissions file so I'm still confused and such a shot-gun solution of just saying `ClamAV` can access everything in `/bin` and below mainly because if this is the solution then I have to add `/sbin` `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` to `AppArmor` as well, and that just seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Please provide the permission information on the folder.

Comment: @Ramhound it's `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 27184 Nov  8 07:49 /bin/true*` for the given executable and
    `drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root       4096 Nov  7 15:11 bin/` for the directory.  But I think it has to do with AppArmor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was AppArmor preventing me from accessing bin.  I changed:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.clamd
```

by adding:

```
/bin/** r,
```

To it and was able to scan the files in /bin.  If I want to add other directories I need to just add lines to that file to include them.  The AppArmor line above means /bin and all child folders, recursively, with read-only access, which is all the ClamAV needs.  The file in question is AppArmor's directive for what special permissions /usr/sbin/clamd will receive which is the ClamAV service daemon.  So this was all I needed to do to get it working.  Thanks @Ramhound for the hint!

Comment: is there any reason you have 2 astericks in your example? I was able to get it working with only 1, ie: `/bin/* r`

Comment: It's been a heck of a long time but if I recall correctly, one * is this directory, two, **, means recurse subdirectories too.

Comment: Thanks thanks, if that’s the case I’ll have to update mine too... let you know what I find. Cheers!

Comment: Confirmed that 2 asterisks indeed means to allow all the sub-directories too. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

I had issues while scanning an imported NFS file system like /data/nfs/dir1/file.jpg

```
clamdscan /data/nfs/dir1/file.jpg: Can't open file or directory ERROR
```

Adding "/data/nfs/* r" in the /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.clamd didn't do the trick for me.
Running the `apparmor_status` shows that clamd process is in enforced mode:

```
2 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/freshclam (18572) 
   /usr/sbin/clamd (18677)
```

So, I've installed the **apparmor-utils** package and than set the clamd process as complain:

```
aa-complain /usr/sbin/clamd
```

Than, I was able to scan the file

```
clamdscan /data/nfs/dir1/file.jpg
/data/nfs/dir1/file.jpg: OK
```

Comment: Same issue, on a vagrant box where the scanned subject was in a synced folder.